# Jenkins: rsync files from directory to another at the same host

Tags: shell, jenkins, rsync

I have jenkins installed on my server: 54.x.x.x 
In jenkins I have a build step (shell) to build angular project and copy folder to /var/www/ at the same host:

```
npm install
npm run build

rsync -avz --delete  -e 'ssh'  ./dist/* appuser@54.x.x.x:/var/www/mybusiness/dist/
```

I already added public key to authorized_keys. 
I can execute it manually and it works, but it fails with jenkins, I got this error:

```
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Why not simply `rsync … dist/ /var/www/mybusiness/dist/`?

Comment: I tried it and I got permission denied

Comment: `sudo -u appuser rsync …`? Or go back to your SSH approach: The error looks like you’re not trusting the SSH server’s key.

Comment: "sudo -u appuser" needs to enter password right? .. yeah, am asking why the ssh approach didnt work, it works when I run the command manually.